# Regex for detecting emojis with condition

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

Let's say we have a string variable which could have emojis in it. I'm trying to find a way to pick those strings which:

- Doesn't have anything other than emojis
- Doesn't have more than 5 emojis

[This repo](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) works pretty well in terms of detecting all kinds emojis, but I'm wondering how can I apply my rules on its regex.

```js
const myRegex = "??"

const mString1 = ""
myRegex.test(mString1) // true

const mString2 = "Text‍"
myRegex.test(mString2) // false

const mString3 = ""
myRegex.test(mString3) // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically what you want is the following:

```js
// detects if string consists of 0 to 5 emojis  
const regex = /^(emoji){0,5}$/;
```

Now the only missing part is the actual emoji-detection inside that regex. We can extract this out of this [emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) library you referenced:

```js
const emojiRegex = require('emoji-regex/RGI_Emoji.js');

const regex = new RegExp("^(" + emojiRegex().source + "){0,5}$", emojiRegex().flags);
```

Didn't test, but something like this should work.